# error: cannot find symbol class ofArgb

Tags: android, compiler-errors, animator

I'm trying to animate colors and I'm getting a strange error in Android Studio. My code:

```
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;

... later ...

ValueAnimator valueAnimator = new ValueAnimator.ofArgb(Color.YELLOW, Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

The following compilation error is thrown:

```
error: cannot find symbol class ofArgb
```

This seems to happen for other methods of ValueAnimator, like ofInt. It doesn't seem to happen for other Animators like ObjectAnimator.ofArgb which gives me a warning that it is SDK 21 and up.

Comment: Drop the `new` - `ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(...);`. `ValueAnimator.ofArgb()` is a static method that returns a `ValueAnimator`.

Comment: Wow, I feel silly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new` slipped in when it shouldn't have. Correct code:

```
ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(Color.YELLOW, Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Which correctly informs me that API 21 is required.

Thanks Mike M.